# JavaScript accordion not working with a form div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that makes rows become accordion. I click on the row, and it open, like a drop down menu. to show the content.

```html
<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This works great with something like this:

```html
<button class="accordion">#define<span class="number-right">48</span></button>
<div id="answer" class="panel">
    <p class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <code>#define</code> a # character is a preprocessor.
        The preprocessor directives are used to provide general instruction
        or required data which is used inside a program.
        in other words: You need this line in order to make the program work
    </p>
</div>
```

But as soon as I have a `<form>` divisive, to use this inside a form tag
the accordion does not work. It opens up, and hides right away, it will not let the content show.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If <button> has not type defined it will be considered a submit button. You also need to  make sure you don't set the event multiple times on the same button.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing that with CSS not Javascript, and also restructure the Html, for example:

```html
    <div class="accordion">
        <button class="accordion-button">#define<span class="number-right">48</span></button>
        <p id="answer" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <code>#define</code> a # character is a preprocessor.
            The preprocessor directives are used to provide general instruction
            or required data which is used inside a program.
            In other words: You need this line in order to make the program work
        </p>
    </div>
```

Then the CSS:

```css
.accordion.active .answer {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .answer {
  display: none;
}
```

Then Javascript:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    const accordion = acc[i];
    const accordionButton = accordion.querySelector('.accordion-button')

    accordionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        accordion.classList.toggle("active");
    });
}
```

Although there are other better ways to achieve it without using javascript at all.

Comment: I tried your code, and is not really working: I got this: http://songnes.com/b/p3.html          - you can see the full code here: http://songnes.com/b/p3.txt  -      Thank you

Comment: I've checked the link you provided, and there's no issue. The accordions are working fine.

Comment: I made the page simple. one accordion is not working, blue background - one accordion works! - the sample page is here: http://songnes.com/b/p3test.html .... and the full code is here, short code: http://songnes.com/b/p3test.txt .... the one that is not working has a form tag ....

Comment: This example in w3schools is also not working with form : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp - see example here not working: songnes.com/b/p3one.html ... and code : songnes.com/b/p3one.txt ....

Comment: You should give the button an attribute of type `button`. If you noticed, the page reloads when you click the button. Its not that it's not working, but the form submits when you click the button which causes the page to reload.

Comment: You should give the button an attribute of type `button`. If you noticed, the page reloads when you click the button. Its not that it's not working, but the form submits when you click the button which causes the page to reload.

Comment: "You should give the button an attribute of type button" thanks for that idea.... can you please tell me how I can do that ... give the button an attribute.

Comment: @VictorM.Barba ```<button type="button">button</button>```